# Javax validation exception when migrating to Wildfly 8.1

Tags: java, validation, migration, wildfly

I am getting the following exception:

> javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151:
>   A method overriding another method must not alter the parameter constraint configuration

when deploying my application on Wildfly 8.1 server. The project is deploying and working well on a previous, JBoss 7.1 application server. Do I need to make changes to the code or could there be some problem with the configuration?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I couldn't find any configuration to help with this problem so I removed parameter constraints from implementation classes, which solved the problem.

Comment: I described the action I took to solve the problem. Wheter you call it a "way" or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 9):

javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException is raised if you add parameter constraints to a method which overrides or implements a super-type method. This behavior is mandated by the Bean Validation spec (see http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-methodlevelconstraints-inheritance) in order to obey to the Liskov substitution principle:

for example below code **Illegally declared parameter constraints on sub class** and it will throw above exception:

```
public class OrderService {

void placeOrder(String customerCode, Item item, int quantity) { [...] }
} 

public class SimpleOrderService extends OrderService {

@Override
public void placeOrder(
    @NotNull @Size(min=3, max=20) String customerCode,
    @NotNull Item item,
    @Min(1) int quantity) {
    [...]
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I face the same problem in my spring boot project, you should move validation annotation where use in override method into super class or interface.

Answer (score 0):

like @Drd said.  I wrote setter method param with `@Valid` in child class,  after remove this annotation,  the error is disappeared.

```
void setAA(@Valid AA aa) {}
```